# Object property constants in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, constants, ecmascript-harmony

I've seen some proposals for ECMAScript Harmony in terms of being able to specify constants with the keyword `const`. However, it seems to be only available in block scopes (i.e., `FunctionBody` and `Program`). Is there a way to define constants as an object property (imagine `myObj.STATUS_OK`)?

I guess the suggested way is to use `properties` via `Object.definePropert(y/ies)`, but that does not seem very convenient, now is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `const` is more related to environment frame bindings, and is thus a slightly different beast to objects and properties.

That said, on globals that's exactly what it does:

```
const a = 10;
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "a");
/*
   Object:
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true
      value: 10
      writable: false
*/
```

If you're looking for shorthand then you can make a pretty simple macro.

In your case, an alternative would be to have a get-only value:

```
var myObj = {
   get STATUS_OK(){ return 42; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea.

Declare them as:

```
var CONST = 
 {
   ONE: 1,
   TWO: 2
 };

Object.seal(CONST);
```

And use them as:

```
   CONST.ONE, CONST.TWO
```