# How to declare an object and its children as a constant?

Tags: javascript, constants

Currently, I'm working on a project for my school whose purpose is to create an object pertaining to math; my object is similar to that of the Native `Math` object, and, as a result, I want to emulate certain aspects of it.

When using the console in Firefox, I have found that certain properties (e.g. `E`, `PI`, and `SQRT2`) cannot be edited (represented by a little lock on them). I know that there is a `const` declaration method, but I've tried both...

```
const obj = {
    prop: function(x){
        return x^3^4;
    },
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "foo"
}
obj.prop = -3.14;
print(obj.prop);    // prints "-3.14"
```

...and...

```
const unEditable = 2.718;
var obj = {e:unEditable};
obj.e = 3;
print(obj.e);    // prints "3"
```

Is there a way to define properties of an object such that said properties cannot be edited by a user? By that, I mean could I assign `obj` a variable `e` with a value `2.718` so that when a person assigns `obj.e` a value of `"Hello, world!`, `obj.e` would still return `2.718`?

#### Notes:

- I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921944/object-property-constants-in-ecmascript), which does not meet the needs of my question.

#### Code Fragmant

```
var Θ = {};
Θ.e = 2.71828;
Θ.pi = 3.14159;
Θ.fac = function(num){
    if(!arguments.length) return NaN;
    return (num<2)?(num<0)?Infinity:1:num*Θ.fac(num-1);
}
Θ.nroot = function(n,m){
    return Θ.pow(n,1/m);
}
```

## Conclusion

An answer based off of [Wingblade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300737/wingblade)'s answer:

```
var Θ = {};
Object.defineProperties(Θ, {
    pi: {
        value: 3.14159,
        writable: false
    },
    e: {
        value: 2.71828,
        writable: false
    }
});
// rest of editable properties go after
```

Comment: Have you read [this article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/) maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `obj.defineProperty` to add a property to an object in a more advanced way that offers more control over how the property will behave, for example if it is writeable or not.

More on this here: [MDN Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

**EDIT:** For defining multiple properties at once you can use [Object.defineProperties()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) like so:

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperties(o, {
  "e": {
    value: 2.71828,
    writable: false
  },
  "pi": {
    value: 3.14159,
    writable: false
  },
  "fac": {
    value: function(num){
        if(!arguments.length) return;
        return (num<2)?(num<0)?Infinity:1:num*o.fac(num-1);
    },
    writable: false
  },
  "nroot": {
    value: function(n,m){
        return o.pow(n,1/m);
    },
    writable: false
  }
});
```

You can actually omit `writeable: false` for all properties, since it defaults to `false` when adding properties using `Object.defineProperty`, but it can be useful to leave it in for readability's sake (especially if you're new to this technique).

Comment: When trying out their example, my console throws me a `TypeError: Object.defineProperty(...)` is not extensible. Is this method universally supported?

Comment: Sorry for the above, CPU glitch.

Comment: The MDN page I linked has a "Browser Compatibility" section, according to it the method is supported rather widely.

Comment: I now have noticed the `.defineProperty()` method only applies to objects which have no properties. Am I correct?

Comment: Not that I'd know of, what exactly are you trying to do? (aka what is your code?)

Comment: I am trying to make my object non-editable by the user (code above).